# Storing multiple powers of matrices in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 1000 matrices with dimensions 2x2.
What I now need to do is to get 30 consecutive powers of those matrices (A^2, A^3... ...A^30) and store them all.

I found a topic that suggested using bsxfun:
[Vectorizing the creation of a matrix of successive powers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921725/vectorisation-of-powers)
However, bsxfun does not work with cell arrays ("Error using bsxfun
Operands must be numeric arrays").

What can I do?
PS. A secondary question: once I have them, I want to plot 4 graphs (each corresponding to 1 of the elements of the 2x2 matrices) with 30 positions (x-axis) which will show confidence bands (16th and 84th percentile).

EDIT: Someone linked to a question that was similar to the one that I linked. From what I can understand, the question there is about a vector, not array of matrices.

Comment: Why do you have them in cell arrays?

Comment: It would make sense to have all of the data in a multi-dimensional array and then `bsxfun` takes care of the rest with *behind-the-scenes* expansion, assuming of course numeric data.

Comment: Why not use a for loop? This is a problem where you should naturally reuse `A^k` to compute `A^(k+1)` anyways.

Comment: Ander: I don't need to have them in cell arrays, it was just the way that I tried to use bsxfun. By default, I store them in a 2x2x1000 matrix.  

Divakar: so how should I implement it? I'm not too good at matlab, so I would appreciate a code if possible.  

Knedlsepp: I want to scale it to higher numbers and I don't want it to take forever.  
PS. IDK why lines don't break, I use 2 spaces... sorry for the formatting!

Comment: @JohnnyQ: Don't underestimate the power of the JIT! `for` loops aren't as slow as you might think. Especially for these simple operations.

Comment: @JohnnyQ So you store them in a cell array for bsxfun, and got an error that you can not use cell arrays in bsxfun. The next logical step is not to use cell arrays!

Comment: @knedlsepp so should I write something like this:  
    for i = 1:1000  
    for k = 1:30   
    C(:,:,k,i)  = A(:,:,i)^k
    end  
    end  
?

Comment: @Ander Yes, but then how do I implement this? I can use the 2x2x1000 matrix, but I don't know how to inform bsxfun that I want powers of the 2x2 matrices.

Comment: Essentially yes, but you can reuse `C(:,:,k-1,i)` to compute `A(:,:,i)^k`, via: `C(:,:,k,i) = C(:,:,k-1,i)*A;`. Of course you need to first preallocate `C` via: `C = zeros(2,2,30,1000)`, copy `C(:,:,1,:) = A` and start the loop at `k=2:30`.

Comment: @knedlsepp I have a problem here: upon writing C(:,:,1,:) = A I get an error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." Indeed, A is 3d and C(:,:,1,:) is 4d.

Comment: Is your array `A` `2-by-2-by-1000`?

Comment: Uh, sorry, you are right, I made a mistake there. Now it is 2x2x1000, but I get a new error: "Error using  * 
Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.

Error in test (line 6)
  C2(:,:,k,i) = C2(:,:,k-1,i)*C;
 " changing to .* does not fix it

EDIT: I found the reason, it should be C(:,:,i) I think
EDIT2: Thanks, it works now! I wish I could upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array `A` is `2-by-2-by-1000`, here are two loops to make things work:

```
A = rand(2,2,1000);
K = 30;
%%
N = size(A,3);
APower = zeros(2,2,N,K);
APower(:,:,:,1) = A;
for i = 1:N
    for k = 2:K
        APower(:,:,i,k) = A(:,:,i)*APower(:,:,i,k-1);
        %// Alternatively you could use: 
        %APower(:,:,i,k) = A(:,:,i)^k;
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand your outer loop at all, or your indexing. Your goal is to create a 2x2x1000 matrix from a single 2x2 matrix, right? So `A(:,:,k) = A(:,:,k-1)*A(:,:,1)`?

Comment: No. As far as I understood the OP wants to compute: the matrix powers `A^k` for `k=1...30` for 1000 different `2-by-2` matrices (stored in a 3D-array layer by layer). Therefore I assume the output should be a `2-by-2-by-1000-by-30` array.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't read far enough into the comments, so the question no longer matches the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the matrix 30 times to do this using cellfun. For example,

```
a = repmat(A{1},1,30);% Select one of your A matrices
b = num2cell(1:30);
x = cellfun(@(a,b) a^b,a,b,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Since you need to run cellfun for each element of A another way is to use arrayfun as below.

```
a = A{1};
b = 1:30;
x = arrayfun(@(b) a^b,b,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: So to use your last idea I have to create a loop? I'm sorry I'm not too good at programming.

Comment: I tried to test your idea:
    for i = 1:1000
        C{i} = rand(2);
 a = C{i};
 b{i} = 1:30;
 x = arrayfun(@(b) a^b,b,'UniformOutput',false);
    end

Comment: And I got and error: Undefined function 'mpower' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
Error in @(b)a^b

Comment: Yes, a loop is needed. cellfun is used only for creating the 30 powers. But it should be possible to use repmat to copy your matrix and use a similar cellfun for all your data.